# How to set .so to be available for LD_PRELOAD

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables

I had an issue when I ran Docker commands:

```
ERROR: ld.so: object 'libgtk3-nocsd.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (failed to map segment from shared object): ignored.
```

After some research I learned that a library provided in the LD_PRELOAD environment variable could not be found. When I run:

```
env | grep LD_
```

I get back:

```
LD_PRELOAD=libgtk3-nocsd.so.0
```

After installing this libgtk3 library via apt-get, I have it located here:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0
```

What's the proper way of setting LD_PRELOAD? Should I overwrite it with the full path to the library, or should I somehow copy this library to make it available globally and leave LD_PRELOAD to it's current value.

I tried adding this to my `~/.profile`:

```
unset LD_PRELOAD
export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0
```

But when I reload my profile, I get back:

```
LD_PRELOAD=libgtk3-nocsd.so.0:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0
```

For some reason, the unset doesn't clear the variable and simply append my path to the existing value and that doesn't work.

Comment: more likely the docker command / script is prepending the value i.e. internally it is doing `LD_PRELOAD=libgtk3-nocsd.so.0:$LD_PRELOAD`

Comment: Right, then it would be better for me if I could mv the .so library somewhere global so that the script doesn't have to be altered and that the environment variable can remain the way it is...

Comment: Does the file actually exist on your system? is the package `libgtk3-nocsd0` installed?

Comment: @steeldriver Yes it does, but the default path defined by docker puts the name, whilst this specific lib doesn't have a global reference anywhere. If I put the full path in the LD_PRELOAD variable it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue. I tested running `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0` in the terminal and it solved the problem for that terminal session. But, when i restarted the terminal, the issue come back.

Thanks to [Sanjay Prajapat](https://askubuntu.com/users/659050/sanjay-prajapat), i added the command to `.bashrc` file in home folder and it solved the issue permanently. However, instead of adding the following line:

```
export LD_PRELOAD=$LD_PRELOAD:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

this one worked for me:

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0
```

(Sorry if there are some grammar mistake).

Edit:

Make sure you have `libgtk3-nocsd.so.0` in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`
[Search it in nautilus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gE5t1.png)

If you didn't have it, try `sudo apt-get install gtk3-nocsd`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding following line in `~/.bashrc` file

```
export LD_PRELOAD=$LD_PRELOAD:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```